# backup berkeley db (java edition)

Tags: database-backup, backup

At the moment I am backing up my Berkley DB databases by taking hard copies of the log/db files periodically. The problem with this approach is that I run out of disk space quite quickly. Is there a way of creating incremental backups, analogous to a transaction log in a relational database?

What I want is only one backup that can never be corrupted (i.e. no Environment Failures on startup).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Incremental backups are described in the javadoc for the DbBackup utility:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17277_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/je/util/DbBackup.html

For a more detailed answer or if you have further questions, please post to the BDB JE forum:
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=273

--mark